# Is there a function in Python that returns a number when it is given the day of the week as an input (string)?

Tags: python, string, function, datetime, dayofweek

The string "Monday" when passed to the function would return 0, and the string "Tuesday" would return 1 and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the attribute from the calendar module:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> getattr(calendar, "monday".upper())
0
```

Comment: Very neat but not portable across locales

Comment: @ArthurKing Well, sometimes ignoring locale is actually a good thing. Otherwise your simple code won't work on a different machine, and he clearly wants the names in English.

Comment: Can you explain the circumstances under which my code would not work?

Comment: @ArthurKing Yes, you go to a German machine on a German locale and type "Monday" like the OP requested :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do so is to create a dictionary:

```py
d = {'Monday': 0, 'Tuesday': 1, 'Wednesday': 3, ...}
```

and then `d['Monday']` would return 1. Wrap it into a function if you want.

Comment: Why a dict when the value are 0, 1, 2,?

Comment: There are many ways to do it, this is one of them.  ```d['Monday']``` returns 1 which is what you want.

Comment: Why do you want 'Monday' to return 1?

Comment: Didn't mean to criticize but to critique ;) When the keys or values are 0, 1, 2, 3, ... the dict might as well be a list

Comment: @re-za nah, you'd prefer a dict, otherwise you have to index one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `calendar` module and are only concerned with English names of weekdays:

```
def weekday_index(name):
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    name = name.title()
    if name in days:
        return days.index(name)
        
    return -1
```

Comment: Why are you calling name.lower() twice? What if the user's locale is French (for example)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the calendar module. This offers the advantage of being locale independent.

```
import calendar

def get_day_num(day):
    try:
        return calendar.day_name[:].index(day.title())
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return -1

print(get_day_num('tuesday'))
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

**Note:**

```
print(get_day_num('dienstag'))
```

...would produce the same result in a German locale

Comment: Good call. However I should think writing the list out is more pedagogical for the OP.

Comment: A question: Why are putting `pass` under the `except` clause instead of directly putting `return -1` there?

Comment: @re-za I always use that construct in case I ever want to add anything more to the code for when an exception arises. Are you trying to tell me it's wrong?

Comment: No I was just curious. Why so hostile?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of days:

```
import calendar
days = dict(zip(calendar.day_name, range(7)))
```

Look up the day:

```
>>> days["monday".title()]
0
```

Comment: What about Sunday ?